# jQuery function filter table multi input

Tags: jquery, filter, html-table

I have this script for filter table:
(change this script into function)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $rows = $('tbody > tr'),
  $filters = $('#tableP input');
  $filters.on("keyup", function () {
    var $i = $filters.filter(function () {
        return $.trim(this.value).length > 0;
    }),
    len = $i.length;
    
    if (len === 0) return $rows.show();
    var cls = '.' + $i.map(function () {
        return this.className
    }).get().join(',.');
    
    $rows.hide().filter(function () {
        return $('td', this).filter(cls).filter(function() {
            var content = this.textContent.toLowerCase(),
                inputVal = $i.filter('.' + this.className).val().toLowerCase();
            return content.indexOf(inputVal) > -1;
        }).length === len;
    }).show();
  });  
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<table id='tableP'>
  <thead> 
      <tr>
        <th>
            <input type='text' class="nome" placeholder="Nome.."/>
        </th>
        <th>
            <input type='text' class="cognome" placeholder="Cognome.." />
        </th>
        <th>
            <input type='text' class="citta" placeholder="Città.."  />
        </th>
      </tr> 
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class='nome'>Carlo</td>
      <td class='cognome'>Grasso</td>
      <td class='citta'>Italia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='nome'>Giuseppe</td>
      <td class='cognome'>Puglisi</td>
      <td class='citta'>Italia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='nome'>Franc</td>
      <td class='cognome'>Justin</td>
      <td class='citta'>Francia</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This works!
I want to create a function to call in the input tag, I do not know how to do it. I want to create a function to call in the input tag, I do not know how to do it.

I want to create function in tag input onkeyup `myFilter()`, how can I do?
Can someone help me?

Comment: Didn't understand what is your goal... what do you mean by *"function to call in the input tag"*. Please, describe your desired result/objective in a more clear way

Comment: I want to turn this script into a function that can be called from the input tag, so I can use this function on many pages by just calling the table name eg. myFilter (IDnameTable)

Comment: i want:
<input type='text' onKeyUp="myFiltro(tableP)"/>

<script>
   myFiltro(tableP);
   ....
  .....
</script>

Comment: I'm studying jquery, I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option:

1. Add a property to identify the `inputs` that you want to use to call the function, in my example I added the property `data-filter="true"`
2. When you start your script, add the listener to those inputs which have that attribute, and get it's parent `<table>`, using `closest(...)` ([Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/closest/))
3. Inside the function, make sure to find just the elements that is children of that table, using `$(table).find()`

That's it, check below if this helps you

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("input[data-filter='true']").on("keydown", function(){
    let parentTable = this.closest('.table-filtered');
    myTableFilter(parentTable);
  });  

  function myTableFilter(table){
    let $rows = $(table).find('tbody > tr');    
    let $filters = $(table).find('input');
    $filters.on("keyup", function () {
      var $i = $filters.filter(function () {
          return $.trim(this.value).length > 0;
      });
      var len = $i.length;
      
      if (len === 0) return $rows.show();
      var cls = '.' + $i.map(function () {
          return this.className;
      }).get().join(',.');
      
      $rows.hide().filter(function () {
          return $('td', this).filter(cls).filter(function() {
              var content = this.textContent.toLowerCase(),
                  inputVal = $i.filter('.' + this.className).val().toLowerCase();
              return content.indexOf(inputVal) > -1;
          }).length === len;
      }).show();
    }); 
  }
});
```

```css
#tableP{
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

#tableP2{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<table id='tableP' class="table-filtered">
  <thead> 
      <tr>
        <th>
            <input type='text' class="nome" placeholder="Nome.." data-filter="true"/>
        </th>
        <th>
            <input type='text' class="cognome" placeholder="Cognome.." data-filter="true"/>
        </th>
        <th>
            <input type='text' class="citta" placeholder="Città.."  data-filter="true"/>
        </th>
      </tr> 
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class='nome'>Carlo</td>
      <td class='cognome'>Grasso</td>
      <td class='citta'>Italia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='nome'>Giuseppe</td>
      <td class='cognome'>Puglisi</td>
      <td class='citta'>Italia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='nome'>Franc</td>
      <td class='cognome'>Justin</td>
      <td class='citta'>Francia</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<table id='tableP2' class="table-filtered">
  <thead> 
      <tr>
        <th>
            <input type='text' class="nome" placeholder="Nome.." data-filter="true"/>
        </th>
        <th>
            <input type='text' class="cognome" placeholder="Cognome.." data-filter="true" />
        </th>
        <th>
            <input type='text' class="citta" placeholder="Città.." data-filter="true" />
        </th>
      </tr> 
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class='nome'>Sir</td>
      <td class='cognome'>Calvin</td>
      <td class='citta'>Brazil</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='nome'>Carlo</td>
      <td class='cognome'>Justin</td>
      <td class='citta'>Francia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='nome'>Franc</td>
      <td class='cognome'>Grasso</td>
      <td class='citta'>Italia</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Basically, What I added is this part:

```
$("input[data-filter='true']").on("keydown", function(){
    let parentTable = this.closest('.table-filtered');
    myTableFilter(parentTable);
 });
```

And inside your function I added the `$(table).find(...)` where it was needed.

Comment: thank you Calvin Nunes, it's what I wanted and that I could not solve.

Comment: sorry Calvin Nunes, if I want to, input not in tr td table
    $("input[data-filter='true']").on("keydown", function(){
    // NOT PARENT --    let parentTable = this.closest('.table-filtered');
    //    myTableFilter(parentTable);
    myTableFilter(('.table-filtered');
     });

how to do?

Comment: sorry @Calvin Nunes, if I want to, input not in tr td table

    `$("input[data-filter='true']").on("keydown", function(){
    // NOT PARENT --    let parentTable = this.closest('.table-filtered');
    //    myTableFilter(parentTable);
    myTableFilter(('.table-filtered');
     });`

how to do?

Comment: Please, since your original question is answered, open a new one, or edit your current question (not modifying the original) adding this question in the end as an **edit**. But I suggest to open a new one. Answering new questions in the comments are not correct